# Deploy error: No such column 'EnhancedLetterheadId' on entity 'EmailTemplate'

Tags: deployment, deployment-error

During upgrading a sandbox environment I receive deploy error:

*Dependent class is invalid and needs recompilation: Class msf.MySalesforceClass: EnhancedLetterheadId, ^ ERROR at Row:11:Column:6 No such column 'EnhancedLetterheadId' on entity 'EmailTemplate'.*

In the sandbox environment I looked into the EmailTemplate object in the Developer Console where I can see that indeed this field is missing. Other sandbox environments do not seem to have this issue.

My first guess was that it had something to do with permission, but I don't see why permissions would be checked for a deployment. Besided, EmailTemplate is a standard Salesforce object where permissions cannot be setup for.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like Enhanced Letterheads are available in your target org. This is a known issue, and you can raise a case with Salesforce if you can't access this feature to request it be enabled in your org.

Here's the known issue documentation for reference: [Enhanced Letterhead Disabled in Org](https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000j5k6lAAA/enhanced-letterhead-disabled-in-org)

Comment: Thanks @Callum MacErlich for you quick response and the link to the documentation.